# aws s3 sync: how to exclude proc, sys directories

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, openvz, aws-cli

I can't seem to get the `aws sync s3` command to exclude directories.  I am backing up a mounted filesystem from OpenVZ which is located at /vz/root/100.

My command is:

```
aws s3 sync /vz/root/100 s3://[mybucket]/vz/root/100 --exclude="proc/*" --exclude="sys/*"
```

I have tried:

```
--exclude="proc/"
--exclude="/proc"
--exclude="*/proc/*"
--exclude="/vz/root/100/proc"
```

No matter what I do, the sync process still recurses through the proc directory.  I saw an issue back in 2013 that exclude wasn't working but it is "fixed" according to them.

```
# aws --version
aws-cli/1.9.5 Python/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-042stab111.12 botocore/1.3.5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what the issue could be, but if there aren't too many subfolders to the `/vz/root/100` directory you could do a workaround by doing the opposite: Exclude everything and include only the subfolders.  `--exclude="*" --include="/vz/root/100/sub1" --include="/vz/root/100/sub2"`

Comment: @Bazze, I considered doing that.  It is through a script, so it's more than just 100.  It does work if I use `*proc*` without any slashes, but then it's likely going to ignore a file with proc in the name that could be important.  It looks like their exclude functionality is still broken.

Comment: Per this ServerFault post, it might be a bug in the CLI tools: http://serverfault.com/q/551457/253490

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me: `--exclude "*/dirname/*"`

Using `aws-cli` version 1.11.103.

Comment: This pattern is working

Comment: it appears the trailing `/*` are required in order to exclude all items inside the dir.

Answer (score 1):

```
--exclude "proc/"
--exclude "/proc"
--exclude "*/proc/*"
--exclude "/vz/root/100/proc"
```

Do not use `=`. Worked for me